# Hacer un Update a una columna cuando otra columna de la misma tabla no es nula SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lo que pasa es que necesito hacer algo como:

```
IF Tabla1.GrupoId3 IS NOT NULL
UPDATE Tabla1 SET GrupoAnexado = 'x' WHERE MiCampo = 'Condiciones'
ELSE
UPDATE Tabla1 SET GrupoId3 = 'x' WHERE MiCampo = 'Condiciones'
```

Pero me marca los siguiente errores:

> 1) Invalid column name 'GrupoId3'.
>
> 2) The multi-part identifier "Tabla1.GrupoId3" could not be bound.

Comment: Existe un error de sintáctico en tu consulta, en la evaluación: `WHERE = 'Condiciones'` contra qué columna quieres evaluarla.

Comment: Hare la correcion, ya que no lo note al momento de escribirlo por aqui gracias

Comment: ¿Quieres que el `IF` considere también `MiCampo = 'Condiciones'`?

Comment: Podrías editar tu pregunta e indicar de forma textual que quieres hacer en los casos que indicas. Por la forma que indicas no se entiende.

Comment: Listo, espero que se pueda comprender un poco mas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entendí correctamente tu pregunta, sería algo así:

```
UPDATE  Tabla1 
    SET GrupoAnexado = CASE WHEN GrupoId3 IS NULL THEN 'x' ELSE GrupoAnexado END,
        GrupoId3 = CASE WHEN GrupoId3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'x' ELSE GrupoId3 END
    WHERE MiCampo = 'Condiciones'
```

La condición para actualizar cada campo dependerá de `GrupoId3` (`NULL` o `NOT NULL`), con los `CASE` verificamos esto y en un caso establecemos el valor y en otro dejamos que sea el mismo campo. El único tema que hay que tener en cuenta, es: si eventualmente tienes un trigger que verifica el `UPDATE` de alguna de estas columnas para hacer algo, esto se ejecutaría también si lo estás actualizando con el mismo valor que ya tiene. Si este fuera el caso, para evitarlo, no queda otra que correr las dos sentencias por separado:

```
UPDATE  Tabla1 
    SET GrupoAnexado = 'X'
    WHERE MiCampo = 'Condiciones'
          AND GrupoId3 IS NULL

UPDATE  Tabla1 
    SET GrupoId3 = 'X'
    WHERE MiCampo = 'Condiciones'
          AND GrupoId3 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Funciono! Muchisimas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Solo sería realizar:

```
UPDATE Tabla1 
SET GrupoAnexado = 'x' 
WHERE 
    MiCampo = 'Condiciones' 
    AND GrupoId3 IS NOT NULL
```

Debido a que el `IF` ya se encuentra evaluado en el `WHERE`.